# PHP, need to obscure numbers in address field

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I'm writing an application for our fire department that will automatically post call data to our web site. For privacy reasons I need to obscure the address for medical calls. The data provided from dispatch could have locations such as

100 Main Street

1555 1st Street

Police Station

Starting at the beginning of the string I need to search for numbers and replace them with an x until I reach a space or letter. So I would end up with:

xxx Main Street

xxxx 1st. Street

Police Station

I started with

```
$address = strtr($address, "1234567890", "xxxxxxxxxx");
```

but found I have a problem when the street is a numbered street such as 1st Street.

I'm now trying

```
$pattern = '/^[0-9]+/';
$replacement = 'x';
$address = preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $address);
```

The expression works when I try it in an online regex tester, but not in my code.

Comment: Better to keep the string of Xs at the same length, regardless of the number of digits. Makes it easy to guess if e.g. it's a single digit and there's only one house on that street.

Comment: The regex looks like it should work. Are you sure the format of `$address` is as expected (e.g. there are no spaces in front)? If you remove the `^` anchor, does it still not match the first group of digits?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
        $address = strtr($address, "1234567890", "xxxxxxxxxx");
```

//You can put the first result in an array like this:

```
        $array = array("xst" => "x", "xnd" => "x", "xrd" => "x", "xth" => "x");
```

//And call the array for the final result like this:

```
        $address = strtr($address, $array);
```